# regular expression to relace fixed characters with space

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need help in doing a simple replace in notepad++.
There is a fixed length of characters which needs to be replaced.
Attached screenshot.

[image: Replace Text]

> ### example:
>
> - {111:001}{121:**7c9cae72-49cb-4ef7-a576-d87af47ae74a**}
> - {111:001}{121:**2f0b8607-07d3-429b-a00c-7ed4b7f73358**}

Common is: {111:001}{121:
And rest till the closing curly braces "}" is dynamic text.
Can someone please assist in creating a replace function to find all the lines
 where the text starts with "{111:001}{121:" and the rest of the characters can be something else until it finds the closing curly brace "}".
if the entire text is found then should replace with blanks.

Comment: which part of your string do you want to replace with space?

Comment: `\s*\{111:001\}\{121:.*\}`

Comment: the entire text. there are othe data within those lines as well. I have just pulled out the one that needs to be replaced. e.g. replace "•{111:001}{121:7c9cae72-49cb-4ef7-a576-d87af47ae74a}" with space or blanks

Comment: Try /^{111:001}{121:.*}/

Comment: hi @Yashas . we tried to find this in notepad++ and it works. however when we try to replace it doesn't work. says 0 occurrences.

Comment: hey thanks. manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yashas solution worked absolutely fine:

> \s*{111:001}{121:.*}

Comment: Huh? You converted my comment into an answer :P

Comment: I needed to vote this answer as correct hence placed in the answer column. hope this is fine.